# How to download a server generated image(generated with user data from client) using express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I want to initiate a download of a server generated image right after it has been generated. I am using fetch to post user input data (no HTML forms). The image does get generated on the server but I can't figure out how to download it to the client afterwards.

NodeJS Code:

```
app.post('/download', (req, res) => {
  const HTML = ArrayToHTML(req.body)
  nodeHtmlToImage({
    output: './image.png',
    html: HTML,
    transparent: true
  })
  res.download('./image.png')
})
```

Client Side Javascript Code:

```
  toServer = (data) => {
    fetch("/download", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
  }
```

What I have tried

1. Trying to download it after `nodeHtmlToImage` has generated the image. This doesn't work because I think the image is not generated yet. Is there a way to make an asynchronous function synchronous?
2. Tacking on a .then to `nodeHtmlToImage` and trying to use `res.download()` in there but nothing happens. No error at client or server.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

The `nodeHtmltoImage` Library can return a buffer of the image. This buffer was sent back as a response to the client. I used `download.js` on the client side to download the returned buffer as an image.

The final code:
Client Side Javascript Code:

```
  toServer = (data) => {
    fetch("/download", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }).then(res => {
      return res.blob()
    }).then(blob => download(blob, data.tableName))
  }
```

NodeJS Code:

```
app.post('/download', async (req, res) => {
  const HTML = ArrayToHTML(req.body)
  console.log("Generating")
  const image = await nodeHtmlToImage({
    html: HTML,
    transparent: true
  })
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'image/png' });
  res.end(image, 'binary');
})
```